# How to update the existing record with many-to-many relationship without creating joining entity class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

**My entities:**

```
public class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }

public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
    }
```

for example imagine that we have existing in the database **one event** with *id=1 categories=null* and **two categories** with *id=1* and *id=2* respectively.

I want records to be created in the joining table using dbContext.Event, example in **SQL**:

```
INSERT INTO EventCategories (CategoryId, EventId) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1);
```

but if suddenly the categories were existed for this event, I want them to be removed

I have tried do the following code but it tries to create a new category:

```
Event ev = await dContext.Events
      .Include(e => e.Categories)
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == 1);
List<Category> fake = new List<Category>() { new Category() { Id = 1 }, new Category() { Id = 2 } };
ev.Categories = fake;
//dbContext.Attach(ev);       I ALSO TRIED TO USE THIS METHOD BUT IT IS IN VAIL
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And this:

```
dbContext.Entry(ev.Categories).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
dbContext.Entry(ev).State = EntityState.Modified;
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Relations is configured via fluent api as follows:

```
            builder
                .HasMany(left => left.Categories)
                .WithMany(right => right.Events)
                .UsingEntity
                (
                    "EventCategory", typeof(Dictionary<string, object>),
                    right => right.HasOne(typeof(Category)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("CategoryId"),
                    left => left.HasOne(typeof(Event)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("EventId"),
                    join => join.ToTable("EventCategory")
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

After a day of torment, I did not find anything better than

```
Event ev = await dbContext.Events
      .Include(e => e.Categories)
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == 1);

int[] desiredCategoriesIDs = { 1, 2 };

ev.Categories = await dbContext.Categories.Where(c => desiredCategoriesIDs.Contains(c.Id)).ToListAsync();

await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```